# 403 Access Denied /public/packages/1.jpg

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, http-status-code-403, chmod

I am trying to access a picture I took from google, on a server running laravel. The photo is named 1.jpg. I have no problem access any of the other pictures in that directory but this one does gives me a 403 error. I have tried setting the chmod to 644 for this photo, but still nothing.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found out how to reset all of the chmod images:

```
find /DIR/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; #for folders
```